# Template empty initially but renders properly on changing and coming back to route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a template named profile which contains three other templates. One of these templates is {{> postlist}}

and the helper function for this template is

```
Template.postlist.helpers({
posts: function() {
return Posts.find({rph: {$in : postsArr}});
}
});
```

The problem is on going to the route, postlist template is empty, since postsArr is calculated later after the dom has loaded on the basis of other two templates. But, if I click on other route and come back to this route, the template renders properly.

What should I do that template renders properly initially itself?

Comment: Put the postsArr in a ReactiveVar or a Session variable, so that your helper will re-run whenever its value changes.

Comment: @sbking: how, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to us `Session`, though it's probably the worst option:

```
Template.postlist.helpers({
  posts: function() {
    return Posts.find({rph: {$in : Session.get('postsArr') }});
  }
});
```

If you now call `Session.set('postArr', ...)` anywhere in your code the `posts` helper will update automatically. The second option is to use a shared reactive variable:

```
var postsArr = new ReactiveVar();
```

and then inside your helper:

```
return Posts.find({rph: {$in : posts.Arr.get() }});
```

Now you can do `postsArr.set(...)` and everything should work fine. Just remember to `meteor add reactive-var` do your project.

One last doubt is: where to put that reactive variable declaration? In most cases you can do away with putting in a single "controller" file. It will work as long as:
- you only have one instance of your template a time
- the code which sets ad gets the value of you reactive variable may be put in the same file

If one of the above conditions does not hold, then the only option to go, which is BTW the best possible, is to put your state variable in your template's scope. This is how you do it:

```
Template.postsList.created = function () {
  this.postsArr = new ReactiveVar();
};

Template.postlist.helpers({
  posts: function() {
    return Posts.find({rph: {$in : Template.instance().postsArr.get() }});
  }
});
```

From helpers you can always access `postsArr` using the `Template.instance()` routine which always return the current template instance, for which the helper was called. From event handlers, note that the second argument of your handler is always the template instance, which you're interested in.

If you need to access it from another templates, then you should probably put your state variable on the corresponding route controller. Assuming you're using `iron-router`, that would be:

```
Iron.controller().state.get('postsArr');
```

The `Iron.controller` routine grants you access to the current route controller. [Read this](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#setting-reactive-state-variables) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly. :)